# issue with getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two fragments and setting them like below

```
fram1 = new FragMent1();
fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rl.getId(), fram1, "fram1");

fram2 = new FragMent2();
fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rl.getId(), fram2, "fram2");
```

Fragment extends Listfragment and not the other.

```
public class FragMent1 extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {

public class FragMent2 extends Fragment{
```

When I perform the line `fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rl.getId(), fram1, "fram1");`

I get the below error message. Anyone know how to solve this?

```
The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragMent1, String)
```

Comment: Use getSupportFragmentManager instead getFragmentManager

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using the support library's Fragments, your Activity will need to extend [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html), and the method to use is [getSupportFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager%28%29).

You might have to always use the support library for your Fragments, rather than the native implementation, until you plan on targeting only API 11 and up.

Answer (score 1):

`FragMent1` should extend `android.app.ListFragment`, not `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`.